# Jaccard Distance calculation using pdist in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as dist

Y=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]

Q=dist.pdist(Y,'jaccard')

print Q
```

The following snippet gives jaccard distance as `1` while it should be `0.5`.
On the other hand if `Y=[[1,2,3],[4,2,3]]` i.e if ordering is changed output is 0.33. But jaccard distance is independent of order of elements. Can you suggest how to resolve this issue here?

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) aren't very clear, but they suggest that the ordering is important: they say that the Jaccard distance is "the proportion of those elements u[i] and v[i] that disagree", which I understand is for fixed i for both elements. That would agree with your results. Anyhow, did you check the implementation in their source code?

Comment: The docstring for the `jaccard` function (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard.html) gives a better description.  `jaccard` computes the Jaccard-Needham dissimilarity for *boolean* arrays.  Its behavior for other array types is not defined, so you shouldn't be passing in arrays of arbitrary integers.

Answer (score 1):

The docstring for the [`jaccard` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard.html) gives a better description of the calculation than the terse summary in the [`pdist` docstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html). `jaccard` computes the Jaccard-Needham dissimilarity for boolean arrays. Its behavior for other array types is not defined, so you shouldn't be passing in arrays of arbitrary integers.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this issue, `pdist` appears to compare arrays by index rather than just what objects are present - so the scipy implementation is order dependent, but the input arrays are not treated as boolean arrays (in the sense that `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]` are not both treated as [`True True True]`, unlike the scipy jaccard function).

I had a similar issue and looked at it here:
[Why are there discrepanices when generating a distance matrix with scipy pdist(metric = 'jaccard') vs scipy jaccard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70549583/discrepanices-when-generating-a-distance-matrix-with-scipy-pdistmetric-jacca/70553656#70553656)